# how to upload image using php function

Tags: php

**This is my code. I tried to upload an image using this `PHP` code. `$mainCName, $mainCImage` save in the database. But, the image does not upload to the `uploadedimage` folder. Can you help me please?.**

```
public function add_main_category($mainCName, $mainCImage){

        $query = "SELECT * FROM mainCategory WHERE mainCName='$mainCName'";

        $result = $this->db->query($query) or die($this->db->error);

        $count_row = $result->num_rows;

        if($count_row == 0){

            $imgfile=$_FILES["$mainCImage"];

        $extension = substr($imgfile,strlen($imgfile)-4,strlen($imgfile));

        $allowed_extensions = array(".jpg",".jpeg",".png",".gif");

        if(!in_array($extension,$allowed_extensions))
        {
            echo "<script>alert('Invalid format. Only jpg / jpeg/ png /gif format allowed');</script>";
        }
        else{
            $imgnewfile=md5($imgfile).$extension;

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["mainCImage"]["tmp_name"],"uploadedimage/".$imgnewfile);

        }

            $query = "INSERT INTO maincategory(mainCName,mainCImage) VALUES('$mainCName','$mainCImage')";

            $result = $this->db->query($query) or die($this->db->error);

            return true;
            }
            else{return false;}

    }
```

Comment: `$_FILES["mainCImage"]["tmp_name"]` -- should that be `"$mainCImage"`?

Comment: @rickdenhaan It is syntax error.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What is the error and on which line?

Comment: Also, `$imgfile=$_FILES["$mainCImage"];` should probably be `$imgfile=$_FILES["$mainCImage"]["name"];` judging by what you're doing with `$imgfile`

Comment: @rickdenhaan I added like this `$imgfile=$_FILES["$mainCImage"]["name"]`. Then name did not save in to the DB.

Comment: Do you get any errors or alerts? If not, does `add_main_category` return `true` or `false`? If `false`, is there already an entry in the `mainCategory` table with the same `$mainCName` value?

Comment: how I can get that ?

Comment: Optimally, you'd have something like Xdebug installed with an IDE where you can set breakpoints. But if that's not the case, you can `var_dump($count_row);` to find out if an entry already exists (it should be `0` if it doesn't) and you could `var_dump(add_main_category($mainCName, $mainCImage));` wherever you call this function to find out if it returns `true` or `false`.